# find\query array of arrays in mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find

how to implement following:
*find value of data3 where id = "ID1" and region = "RegionA" and indicator_id"=1* (result should be exactly: "A")

elements' collection:

```
{
    "id" : "ID1",
    "data1" : 
    [ 
        {
            "region" : "RegionA",
            "data2" : [ 
                {
                    "indicator_id" : 1,
                    "data3" : "A"
                }, 
                {
                    "indicator_id" : 2,
                    "data3" : "B"
                }, 
                {
                    "indicator_id" : 3,
                    "data3" : "C"
                }, 
                {
                    "indicator_id" : 4,
                    "data3" : "D"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "region" : "RegionB",
            "data2" : [ 
                {
                    "indicator_id" : 5,
                    "data3" : "A"
                }, 
                {
                    "indicator_id" : 6,
                    "data3" : "B"
                }, 
                {
                    "indicator_id" : 7,
                    "data3" : "C"
                }, 
                {
                    "indicator_id" : 8,
                    "data" : "D"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

dont use $where as it is inefficient

following works but return the entire 'RegionA' (which is not the expected result) and uses '[0].data1[0].data2[0].data3' to project "A":

```
db.elements.find({id:"ID1"},{data1 : { $elemMatch: { data2: {$elemMatch: { indicator_id:1}}}}})[0].data1[0].data2[0].data3
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try following

```
db.test1.find({id:"ID1",data1:{$elemMatch: { region:"RegionA"}}, "data1.data2.indicator_id":1 })
```

hope this what you looking for.

Comment: didn't work for me. I think I need to use $elemMatch twice since I use an Array within an Array. I come to think this model is wrong in the first place (for Mongo)

Comment: i am not sure why it did not work for you, but i have taken document from your post and run above query and it works perfectly fine, and i also try with single condition out of 3 condition it also worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you got it right by saying that the data model may not be right.
It looks like you are trying to keep SQL like tables, and just embedded relations as sub-documents.
The problem is that you are trying to make queries deeply into these sub-documents.
What you would need is to apply the '$elemMatch' operator to the sub-documents, but this is not supported.
See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831
And even if it was supported, the queries would be way too complex and you would have difficulty declaring indexes on such data.

As an alternative for the current query, you can use the aggregation framework.

```
db.elements.aggregate([{"$match":{"id":"ID1"}},{"$unwind":"$data1"},{"$unwind":"$data1.data2"},{"$match":{"data1.region":"RegionA","data1.data2.indicator_id":1}},{"$project":{"answer":"$data1.data2.data3","_id":0}}]).result

[ { "answer" : "A" } ]
```

Even if the above aggregation query works and may be fine for a small amount of data, I suggest that you look at the queries you need to perform and model your data accordingly.

For example, if the above is your most important query, you may want to consider having one document per 'data3' item. Your data would look like the documents you see once your run the 2 $unwind commands in the above aggregation query:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("52caeb934c735353309cf068"),
        "id" : "ID1",
        "region" : "RegionA",
        "indicator_id" : 1,
        "data3" : "A"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("52caeb934c735353309cf068"),
        "id" : "ID1",
        "region" : "RegionA",
        "indicator_id" : 2,
        "data3" : "B"
    },
    ...
```

To learn more on modeling, watch the presentations from MongoDB.
Go to http://www.mongodb.com and search for 'presentations data modeling'